# How to use conditional statement and return value for a function in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have to create a function as: ans(x) which returns the value 2*abs(x), if x is 
negative, and the value x otherwise. What command could i use?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try before asking this question?  The reason you got negative points is because your question doesn't show that you did anything in advance of asking your question.  Please consult the StackOverflow Q&A protocol.  You will learn more by trying something first, and so will other people who view your postings.

Answer (score 2):

```
ans <- function(x){
  ifelse(x < 0, 2*abs(x), x)
}
```

will do.

```
> ans(2)
[1] 2

> ans(-2)
[1] 4
```

Explanation:
We can use the built-in base `R` function `ifelse()`. The logic is pretty simple:

`ifelse(condition, output if condition is TRUE, output if condition is FALSE)`

Therefore, `ifelse(x < 0, 2*abs(x), x)` will do the following:

1. evaluate whether value x is negative (<0)
2. if `TRUE`, return `2*abs(x)`
3. if `FALSE`, return `x`

The advantage of `ifelse()` over traditional `if()` is the vectorization. `if()` can only handle a single value, `ifelse()` will evaluate any vector given as input.

Comparison:

```
ans_if <- function(x){
  if(x < 0){2*abs(x)}else{x}
}
```

This is the same function, using a traditional `if()` structure. Giving a single value as input will result in the same output for both functions:

```
> ans(-2)
[1] 4
> ans_if(-2)
[1] 4
```

But if you want to input multiple values, let's say

```
test <- c(-1, -2, 3, -4)
```

the `ifelse()` variant will evaluate every element of the vector and generate the correct output as a vector of the same length:

```
> ans(test)
[1] 2 4 3 8
```

whereas the `if()` variant will throw a warning

```
> ans_if(test)
[1] 2 4 6 8
Warning message:
In if (x < 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and return the wrong output, as only the first value was used for evaluation (-1) and the operation over the whole vector was based on this evaluation.

Comment: thanks. actually i am doing some online excercise, that's why i needed this. Can you please explain this argument. why we have used ifelse here, why not only if and why there is x again after 2*abs(x). I mean can you please explain a little what that mean the whole logic behind the command you recommended?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: another thing if someone could explain please. I have to create a function  ans(x, y, c) which returns the value c*x^2*y, if 
x^2 <= y <= 1, and the value 0 otherwise. I am using the following command:  

ans<-function(x,y,c){
+ ifelse(x^2 <= y <= 1, c*x^2*y, 0)}

what is wrong with this, because R is not accepting it.

Comment: Why the `+`? Is it a typo?

Comment: sorry yes + is a typo. Can you please guide what could be problem in my command?

Comment: This should work: `ans<-function(x,y,c){ifelse(x^2 <= y & y <= 1, c*x^2*y, 0)}` R cannot handle a condition like `x < y < 1`, you need to split them into two and combine with `&`. Also, writing `cx` will cause R to look for an object called `cx`. If you want to multiply `x` with `c`, you need to use the `*` operator.